# Why is my output file different than the original?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a simple helper class that takes data from a file, edits it then writes it back as a byte array.
The problem I encounter happens when writing the file, it somehow corrupts the data so my file becomes unusable.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
FileOutputStream bytewriter = new FileOutputStream(output_file_name);

byte[] bytedata = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myPath"));

byte[] result = edited_data.getBytes();

bytewriter.write(result);

bytewriter.close();
```

Even when I just write the original data without editing back, the output file differs in one hex value so the program that uses the file thinks its corrupted( I am using a simple hex editor to check for differences ).

Is there a simpler/better way to do what I am trying to do without corrupting the file? Why does the corruption even happen? I tried almost every possible combination of Writing/Reading the file and it happens every time.

Sorry for the long question and spelling mistakes, any advice/help is appreciated. Have a nice day :D

Comment: What kind of file is it? It is an image or pdf file? Should you be using `Binary` Mode or `Text` Mode?

Comment: Should you be including an encoding?

Comment: How are you getting from `bytedata` to `edited_data`?

Comment: did you mix up `edited_data` with `bytedata` in your snippet? It's completely unclear what happens during editing, so no one can say if you're doing somthing wrong or better.

Comment: You seem to be reading bytedata and then not using it. You're saving edited_data.getBytes() instead. I assume your UI is editing the data and then you're saving that. So, you're going to have to look at what translate the byte arrays into your UI and out of it (between lines 2 and 3 above). It is likely to be a character encoding issue.

Comment: Thanks ManoDestra, you got me on the right track. I did some testing with byte result[] = test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.*******);  encoding definitely seems to be the issue. Now I only have to find out how the original file is encoded :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys/girls for your help, I finally solved the issue. The problem was that I did not specify any encoding before writing the data. This line below solved the problem:

```
byte result[] = edited_data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

The output is no longer corrupted and everything works as I intended. :D

Comment: You never mentioned in your question what `edited_data` was and how you created it and you didn't respond to @Ulrich's question about it. In other words you posted a question that only you could resolve since you didn't mention information that was critical to resolving the issue.